# Pintar barra superior de título de uma tabela com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como eu faço para pintar a barra superior de título de uma tabela feita com bootstrap?

Para pintar toda TR do thead.

```
<div class="pull-right" id="tabela4">
  <br />
  <table class="table table-striped table-ordered table-bordered col-md-4">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Tipo</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Descrição</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Usuário</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Data de Inclusão</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.ID_CRM_Evento + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.ID_TipoEvento  + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.DE_Descricao  + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + this.DE_Usuario + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + getFormattedDate(this.DT_Inclusao) + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + this.DE_Status + '</small></td>
        <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Visualizar</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá meu caro, poste o seu código html, assim poderemos auxiliá-lo, de toda forma, basta você escrever um css com as alterações que você precisa, sem modificar o css do bootstrap, e coloque o link do seu css após o css do bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer em seu CSS

```
table thead tr td {background-color:red;}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AWQ3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right" id="tabela4">
            <br />
            <table class="table table-striped table-ordered table-bordered col-md-4">
            <thead >
            <tr class="paint">
            <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Tipo</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Descrição</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Usuário</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Data de Inclusão</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.ID_CRM_Evento + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.ID_TipoEvento  + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><small>' + this.DE_Descricao  + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + this.DE_Usuario + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + getFormattedDate(this.DT_Inclusao) + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><small>' + this.DE_Status + '</small></td>
                    <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Visualizar</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.paint{
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Exemplo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyamarante/3YrhR/1/

Vamos dizer que você também queira remover as linhas(bordas) das colunas, poderá usar no css:

```
thead > tr > td{
    border: none !important;
        border-collapse:collapse;
}
```